# Uploading large files via XHR fails with Chrome, works with Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload

I am uploading video files to my server. The files are at least 20MB, some over 100MB.

For improved user experience, I upload via JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest, this way I can display upload speed and remaining time.

And to avoid and trouble on the server (such as requests timing out and taking too long to process) I submit the file in little packages on the server, and have a php script re-assemble the file.

My script works great, with one weird catch - and until just now I thought it was because of my ISP.

Using Google chrome I can upload files up to 20MB with no problems. But anything larger gets errors: For example my 100MB file will not send anything to the server - the second package never arrives. On my 50MB file it happens after around 47%, with the 7th package. And another file doesn't even send the first package.

I restarted my computer, and it keeps happening at the same position/package number for each file - though the position has nothing in common compared to the other failed files.

It doesn't matter if you try to start after one of the failed packages, say If I start at #8 if 7 failed - it will continue to fail. If I ignore errors (rather than to try again) it will just send the rest of the file in empty chunks.

I had already tried from a different internet connection, though I had to use firefox there. And it worked fine. So I install firefox on my machiene, and BAM works like a charm, correctly sending the 100MB file.

What could be going wrong on Chrome?

```js
$(document).on('click','#video_upload',function(evt){
 uploadProcess('vod_video_file');
});


function toBlob(text)
{
 var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
 var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0);

 for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);

 if(typeof window.Blob == "function")
 {
   var blob = new Blob([data]);
 }else{
   var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
   bb.append(data);
   var blob = bb.getBlob();
 }
 return blob;
}

function splitFile(dataArray, size) {

 blobs = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.size; i += size)
 {
  var copy = dataArray.slice();
  var partial = copy.slice(i, i+size);
  blobs.push(partial);
    }
 return blobs;
}

function uploadProcess(fileInputId)
{
 var file = document.getElementById(fileInputId).files[0]; 
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
 
 reader.onloadend  = function(evt)
 {
  var fr = evt.target.result; 
  fileUpload( fr );
 }
 
}

function fileUpload(inputDataArray)
{
 var since;
 var intervalid;
 var totalBytes = inputDataArray.length;
 var packets = new Array();
 
 var packetNum = 0;
 var packetCount = 0;
 var packetSize = 0;
 
 function startUpload()
 {
  intervalid = setInterval(function(){updateUploadStats();},1000);
  calculatePaketSize()
  createPackets();
  submitPacket();
 } 
 
 function calculatePaketSize()
 {
  var ideal_size = 3*1024*1024;
  var packet_count = Math.ceil( totalBytes/ideal_size);
  packetSize = Math.ceil(totalBytes/packet_count);
 }

 function createPackets()
 { 
  packets = splitFile(toBlob(inputDataArray), packetSize)
  packetCount = packets.length;
 }
 
 function updateUploadStats(e)
 {
  //displaying upload progress in GUI
 }
 
 function submitPacket()
 {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", 'index.php?controller=AdminVodVideo&action=VideoUpload&ajax=1&r='+packetNum+'&token='+token, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/octet-stream");
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary = function(text){
   this.send(text);
  }
  
  var eventSource = xhr.upload || xhr;
  
  eventSource.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
   updateUploadStats(e);
  });
  
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
   if(xhr.readyState == 4)
   {
    if(xhr.status == 200)
    {
     //server will return the string 'upload failed' if the file to be received was empty.
     
     if( xhr.responseText == 'upload failed')
     {
      console.log('FAILED , trying again in 3 s');
      setTimeout(submitPacket,3000);
     }
     else
     {
      updateUploadStats();
      packetNum++;
      if(packetNum == packetCount)
      {
       processOnServer();
      }
      else
      {
       submitPacket();
      }
     }
     

    }else{
     // process error
     console.log('we got a 500 error'); 
    }
   }
  };
  since = Date.now();
  xhr.mySendAsBinary( packets[packetNum] );
 }
 
 function processOnServer()
 {
  //telling the server to piece the file back together.
 }
 
 startUpload();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/sthielen/BigUpload) it claims to be able to do the same thing you're trying.

Comment: I am having the same problem with mozilla firefox and xhr. Did you solve this problem, and how?

Comment: Yes i think I ended up uaing the "big upload" library that was posted in the xomment above. In the very end tho I resorted to a 3rd party service provider to handle all my files.